# Is there a term that incorporates both PDFs and PMFs?

Tags: probability-theory, notation, terminology

Assume that $f$ and $g$ have been defined ass the PDFs of continuous random variables, and that $h$ has been defined as the PMF of a discrete random variable. Is it then acceptable to say:
\begin{align}
\text{...which is determined by the probability distribution functions } f, g, \text{ and }h.
\end{align}
Is there a better term than "probability distribution function" that incorporates both PDFs and PMFs?

Comment: probability function?

Comment: Yes, that already feels better, and may be as good as it gets.

Comment: I use "density" for both even though some people like to reserve that for discrete r.v.s.  I think "probability distribution function" would make most people think of the c.d.f.

Comment: One of the random variables is inherently discrete (takes values in a finite set) and density would feel out of place. What about "probability distributions", or "generalized density functions" to be technically correct?